# How can I remove the Image from Button ,Swift?

Tags: swift

I'm very new to Swift . ,I tried to remove image from button but i couldn't do it ,

I follow some tutorial and now can add image to Button. but have no idea how to remove it. 
XOButtonsCollection.index(of: sender).remove

Comment: Hi @Saad welcome to StackOverflow. Please show a meaningful code snippet so others can try to reproduce the problem and help you more effectively.
Also have a look at [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to see how you can write a question that quickly will get you an answer.

Answer (score 1):

```swift
sender.setImage(nil, for: .normal)
```